# Unable to access data structure after `open()` and `mmap()` - Bus Error

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory, mmap

I'm writing a `fork()` based server and I need to have an array shared between the parent process and its' forked children. I was specifically requested to use a file and `mmap()` for the implementation so I will be able to use `fcntl()` locks easily later on.

For some reason, when I try to execute the code below, I'm getting `Bus Error` on the line `struct_array[i].number = -1;`.

```
if ((fd = open("/tmp/tmp-file", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 777)) == -1) {
    perror("open");
}

struct my_struct *struct_array = mmap(NULL, struct_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

if (struct_array == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
}

for (i = 0; i < CLIENTS_SIZE; i++) {
    struct_array[i].number = -1;
}
```

I went over the man pages again and again but there's must be something I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing an address within a mapped memory range yields bus error if the corresponding offset falls beyond the end of file.

In this particular case the file size is zero, you should make the file at least *struct_size* bytes long (use ftruncate).